# emacs install fails under 18.10

Tags: apt, emacs

Installing emacs under 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) fails

When I search for libotf, it is there:

```
locate libotf.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libotf.so
```

So why does fixing the install fail?

```
sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up emacs-gtk (1:25.2+1-11) ...
Install emacsen-common for emacs
emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs
emacs: error while loading shared libraries: libotf.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: install script from emacsen-common package failed
dpkg: error processing package emacs-gtk (--configure):
 installed emacs-gtk package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs25:
 emacs25 depends on emacs-gtk (>= 1:25); however:
  Package emacs-gtk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package emacs25 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs-gtk
 emacs25
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try this: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libotf.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libotf.so.0` and try again.

Comment: added your symbolic link, sudo apt remove emacs-gtk, then sudo apt install emacs-gtk.  Same problem

Answer (score 2):

```sh
sudo apt install libotf0
```

worked for me.
You might also need to install `libm17n-0`